# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=Oxf0) on Button Click

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

This is a Lazarus project.

It happens when I press `Button4`. I have a few ideas what could be the reason, but I really have no idea how to fix this.

The error is:

```
Projekt EnglischOlympics 
»Process stopped with reason:
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=Oxf0)
Address 10000C61E*

Assambler:
*000000010000C5DE                          :  48 83 7b 08 00                 cmpq   $0x0, 0x8(%rbx)*
```

The Interface unit:

```
unit Oberflache;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  uZaehler, uSpeicher; //Hier eigene Units eingebunden

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Zaehler:TZaehler; //Objekte deklarieren
  Speicher:TSpeicher;
implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Zaehler := TZaehler.Create;   // Objekte erzeugen
  Speicher := TSpeicher.Create;
  Zaehler.SetzeSchulNr(1);
  Zaehler.SetzeSchulerNr(1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Zahl : integer;
begin
  Zahl := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  Speicher.AnzahlSchulen(Zahl);
  Zaehler.AnzahlSchulen(Zahl);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bezeichnung : string;
begin
  Bezeichnung := Edit2.Text;
  Speicher.EingabeSchulen(Bezeichnung);
  Zaehler.SchulNrHoch(1);

  If Zaehler.GibSchulNr > Zaehler.GibAnzahlSchulen
  then
  begin
    Zaehler.SetzeSchulNr(1);
    Label1.Caption := 'Name der Schule: ' + IntToStr(Zaehler.GibSchulNr);
    Edit2.Text := 'Name der Schule';
    Zaehler.SetzeSchulerNr(1);
    Label2.Caption := Speicher.GibSchule;
  end;

  Edit2.Text := 'Name der Schule';
  Label1.Caption :='Name der Schule: ' + IntToStr(Zaehler.GibSchulNr);

  Label4.Caption := IntToStr(Zaehler.GibAnzahlSchulen);
  Label5.Caption := IntToStr(Zaehler.GibSchulNr);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Zaehler.Free;
  Speicher.Free;
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bezeichnung : string;
begin
  Bezeichnung := Edit3.Text;
  Speicher.EingabeSchuler(Bezeichnung);
  Zaehler.SchulerNrHoch(1);

  Label1.Caption := 'Name des Schülers: ' + IntToStr(Zaehler.GibSchulerNr);
  Edit2.Text := 'Name des Schülers';
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

This unit counts what number we're on:

```
UNIT uZaehler;

interface

//--------------------  ggf Uses-Liste einfügen !  --------------------
//uses ....;

type
   TZaehler = CLASS

     // weitere Attribute
     private
        SchulerNr : integer;
        SchulNr : integer;
        AnzahlS : integer;

     // weitere Methoden
     public
        procedure AnzahlSchulen (pAnzahlS : integer);
        function GibAnzahlSchulen : integer;

        procedure SetzeSchulerNr (pSchulerNr: integer); virtual;
        procedure SchulerNrHoch (pUm: integer); virtual;
        function  GibSchulerNr : integer; virtual;

        procedure SetzeSchulNr (pSchulNr: integer); virtual;
        procedure SchulNrHoch (pUm: integer); virtual;
        function GibSchulNr : integer; virtual;

   end;

implementation

//+---------------------------------------------------------------------
//|         Zaehler: Methodendefinition 
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------

//-------- SetzeSchulerNr (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TZaehler.SetzeSchulerNr (pSchulerNr: integer);
begin
  SchulerNr := pSchulerNr;
end;

//-------- Gib Anzahl Schulen (public) -------------------------------------
function TZaehler.GibAnzahlSchulen : integer;
begin
  Result := AnzahlS;
end;

//-------- Anzahl Schulen (public) ---------------------------------------
procedure TZaehler.AnzahlSchulen (pAnzahlS: integer);
begin
  AnzahlS := pAnzahlS;
end;

//-------- GibSchulerNr (public) ---------------------------------------
function TZaehler.GibSchulerNr : integer;
begin
  Result := SchulerNr;
end;

//-------- SchulerNrHoch (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TZaehler.SchulerNrHoch (pUm: integer);
begin
  SchulerNr := SchulerNr + pUm;
end;

//-------- SetzeSchulNr (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TZaehler.SetzeSchulNr (pSchulNr: integer);
begin
  SchulNr := pSchulNr;
end;

//-------- SchulNrHoch (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TZaehler.SchulNrHoch (pUm: integer);
begin
  SchulNr := SchulNr + pUm;
end;

//-------- GibSchulNr (public) ---------------------------------------
function TZaehler.GibSchulNr : integer;
begin
  Result := SchulNr;
end;

end.
```

This unit saves the current data:

```
UNIT uSpeicher;

interface

//--------------------  ggf Uses-Liste einfügen !  --------------------
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, uZaehler; //Hier eigene Units eingebunden

type
   TSchuler = record   // Ein Schüler mit Namen, 6 Punktzahlen können eingegebn werden,
     SName: string;    // daraus ergibt sich TotalScore (Gesamtpunktzahl)
     Score1: real;
     Score2: real;
     Score3: real;
     Score4: real;
     Score5: real;
     Score6: real;
     TotalScore: real;
   end;

   TSchule = record     // Ein Team hat einen Namen und mehrere Schüler vom Typ TSchuler
     TName: string;   // der TeamScore wird aus den einzelnen TotalScores berechnet
     Schueler: Array[1..8] of TSchuler;
     TeamScore: real;   //Wird aus allen TotalScores berechnet
   end;

   TSpeicher = CLASS

   // weitere Attribute
     private

   // weitere Methoden
     public

        Teams : Array of TSchule;

        procedure AnzahlSchulen (pAnzahl: integer);
        procedure EingabeSchulen (pName: string);
        procedure EingabeSchuler (pName: string);
        procedure ZahlenAktualisieren;
        function GibSchule : string;

   end;

   var
   SchuleZahl : integer;
   SchulerZahl: integer;

implementation

//+---------------------------------------------------------------------
//|         Speicher: Methodendefinition 
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------

//-------- Anzahl Festlege (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TSpeicher.AnzahlSchulen (pAnzahl: integer);
begin
  SetLength(Teams, pAnzahl); //Anzahl der Schulen festlegen
end;

//-------- Eingabe Schulen (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TSpeicher.EingabeSchulen (pName: string);
var
  i: integer;
  Zaehler: TZaehler;
begin
  Zaehler := TZaehler.Create;
  i := Zaehler.GibSchulNr;
  Teams[i].TName := pName;

  Zaehler.Free;
end;

//-------- Zahl Schule Aktualisieren (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TSpeicher.ZahlenAktualisieren;
var
  i, h: integer;
  Zaehler: TZaehler;
begin
  Zaehler := TZaehler.Create;
  i := Zaehler.GibSchulNr;
  h := Zaehler.GibSchulerNr;
  SchuleZahl := i;
  SchulerZahl := h;
  Zaehler.Free;
end;

//-------- Eingabe Schuler (public) -------------------------------------
procedure TSpeicher.EingabeSchuler (pName: string);
var
  i: integer;
  n: integer;
  Zaehler: TZaehler;
begin
  Zaehler := TZaehler.Create;
  i := Zaehler.GibSchulNr;
  n := Zaehler.GibSchulerNr;
  Teams[i].Schueler[n].SName := pName;
  Zaehler.Free;
end;

//-------- GibSchule (public) ---------------------------------------
function TSpeicher.GibSchule : string;
begin
  Result := Teams[SchuleZahl].TName;
end;

end.
```

I played around with changing the input for `Teams[i].Schueler[n].SName := pName;` in `procedure TSpeicher.EingabeSchuler()` in `Speicher`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Trace into your own subroutines to find the exact line that triggers the error. Which line is it? What values do the variables have at the error location?

Comment: @Tom Burnberg thanks for the tips. Yet I have no Idea how to actually do this. I think i fixed my code now but how would I do what you told me just so I know what to do next time?

Comment: In Delphi you put a breakpoint on a line where you want to start tracing. When the execution stops there, you can use {F7} to trace into subroutines and {F8} to execute the line where the cursor is. Variable values you can see by defining watch's or moving the mouse cursor over variables. If you have solved the error you can answer your own question.

Comment: Regarding the tags, please only use one product name tag and one version tag (e.g. `Delphi`, `Delphi-7`), and of course only the one that you are using. Do not list all pascal tools you know.

Comment: Skimming through your code, the two classes `TZaehler` and `TSpeicher` are missing `constructor` methods, and you are also not calling the constructors anywhere in your code. Yet you are attempting to access some of their methods or fields in various places, therefore the error messages.

Comment: In short, your code is incomplete and therefore you get error messages. You need to read about classes, how to define them and how to implement them.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've been able to fix the problem by removing the create and free from the methods in the Speicher Unit, I'll try to use ur tips :)